# How to disable automatic horizontal to vertical conversion in Bootstrep 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this code in a page in bootstrap 3.

```
                            <div class="description_text">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Sunny -->
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        <img src="img/sunnylogo.png" alt="Sunny logo">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        Sunny
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Sunny -->

                                <!-- Walking -->
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        <img src="img/walkinglogo.png" alt="Walking logo">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        Walking
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Walking -->

                                <!-- Windy -->
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        <img src="img/windylogo.png" alt="Windy logo">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        Windy
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Windy -->

                                <!-- Rain -->
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        <img src="img/rainlogo.png" alt="Rain logo">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        Rain
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Rain -->

                                <!-- Snow -->
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        <img src="img/snowlogo.png" alt="Snow logo">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="horizontal_center">
                                        Snow
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Snow -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

When window is full screen, it is OK.
[image: Normal]

But if I make it small, it making problem.

It goes to vertically.

[image: 2]

I want to stop this property of bootstrap in this page.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: If you want to tweak how it looks on XS or SM screens, then add XS/SM grid classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use more then one class according to resolution

`col-md-2` Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)

`col-sm-2` Small devices Tablets (≥768px)

`col-xs-2` Extra small devices Phones (<768px)

Use

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
```

Comment: No! This is *very* redundant and equivalent to simply `<div class="col-xs-2"></div>`. Read https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Answer (score -1):

Simply don't use bootstrap's col-md-x and row classes. Make your own divs and style them by yourself.

Or you could style the col-md-2 class like so:

```
.col-md-2{
    float: left;
}
```